# Installing feynmp / feynmf to TexMaker

Tags: preamble, feynmf, feynmp-auto

What packages do I need to download and what I need to have in my preamble in order to use `feynmp` and `feynmf` in `texmaker`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `texmaker` is a front-end editor for LaTeX. You don't use packages and TeX related software "in texmaker". In fact its the other way around: `texmaker` uses (La)TeX and its associated software.

Comment: Regarding your question: If your distro is configurated such that missing packages get downloaded and installed on the fly (default case) than a simple `\usepackage{feynmf}` in the preamble will do the job.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If not what problems did you encounter? If yes, you might accept my answer, so the issue is closed.

Answer (score 2):

`texmaker` does not organise the (La)TeX software bundle. It only makes use of it. Hence, you don't have to change anything in this particular program to run the `feynmf` package. The installation of LaTeX packages normally is done outside of the editor and is quite straightforward. (If you're not sure about it have a quick read. There is plenty of resources online, especially here on TeX.SX!)

When you are done installing the package try to compile the following file through `pdflatex`. Note that you also need `metafont`. Both, `pdflatex` and `metafont` should be present in your TeX distro as they are canonical programs in the bundle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmf}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(120,80)
  \fmfleft{i1,i2}
  \fmfright{o1,o2}
  \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
  \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
  \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

If this doesn't succeed try the following compilation cycle:

```
pdflatex <name of your test file>.tex
mf '\mode:=laserjet; input diagram'
pdflatex <name of your test file>.tex
```

`feynmp` (as an interface for `metapost`, resp.) is used analogously.